# expected struct `Weight`, found integer

Tags: rust, weight, parity-bridges-common, weighttofee, frame-support

I was making parity-bridges-common compatible to the stable version of `polkadot-v0.9.32`. I'm getting the error:

```
expected struct Weight , found integer.
```

Because earlier the weight in the frame-support was u64 but now it`s struct Weight

```rs
struct Weight
 {
    #[codec(compact)]
    /// The weight of computational time used based on some reference hardware.
    ref_time: u64,
    #[codec(compact)]
    /// The weight of storage space used by proof of validity.
    proof_size: u64,
}
```

Can someone please guide me through this.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should convert u64 to Weight struct

Try this `from_parts` method :https://paritytech.github.io/substrate/master/src/sp_weights/weight_v2.rs.html#118

Example:

`Weight::from_parts(25_000_000, u64::MAX)`

Comment: thank you @CocDap

Answer (score 2):

Since weight is now two dimensional, you need to provide a *Proof size* component as well.
The exact value for this depends on the use-case; exactly like the exact *Reference Time* component depends on the use-case. `u64::MAX` should just be a place holder and not a default value.

You can then use `Weight::from_parts` instead of a simple `u64` to construct a `Weight` instance.